# how to pass id from jsp to bootstrap modal delete confirmation ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pass an id from a table in a `jsp` page to a bootstrap modal of delete confirmation ..

this is my button :

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-delete ="${user.id}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

and this is the modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>You are about to delete a User, this procedure is
                        irreversible.</p>
                    <p>Do you want to proceed ?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="delBtn">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is a script that I've used to invoque `delete` url :

```
 $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

$('#delBtn').click(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {

    var   deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
       url:"<c:url value='/supprimer/" + deleteid + "'/>",
        data: ,
        success: function(data) 
        {
       }
    });

});
});
 });
```

this is the dispacher Controller :

```
  @RequestMapping("/supprimer/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){

    this.userService.deleteData(id);
    return "redirect:/utilisateurs";
}
```

my work seems to be logic :/ but I don't know why this is not working ?

I tried this `script` too but it didn't work :

```
     $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');
    alert(deleteid);

 $('#delBtn').attr('onClick', "location.href="<c:url value='/supprimer/" + deleteid + "'/>"");
 });
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This script is totally upside down

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#delBtn').click(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');
            $.ajax({
                 cache: false,
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: "<c:url value='/supprimer/" + deleteid + "'/>",
                 data: ,
                 success: function(data) {}
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Whole script should be inside `$(document).ready(function() {}`

above script should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');
            $('#delBtn').click(function() { //beter if use `onClick` function
                $.ajax({
                     cache: false,
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: "<c:url value=/supprimer/" + deleteid + "/>", //there were also extra commas here
                     data: ,
                     success: function(data) {}
                });
            });
    });
});
```

And in your second script, with your approach

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');
  alert(deleteid);
  $('#delBtn').attr('onClick', "location.href='<c:url value=/supprimer/" + deleteid + "/>'");
});
```

OR attempt like this

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var deleteid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('delete');
  alert(deleteid);
  $('#delBtn').attr('onClick', "location.href='/supprimer/" + deleteid + "'");
});
```

Problem in your scripts you have extra commas, should check the console and rendered HTML